# Doubt regarding energy conservation

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, energy, energy-conservation, vectors

I have a doubt regarding the conservation of energy. While solving questions of the same, I have a hard time deciding whether I should conserve energy along one axis or do so in the vectorial form. Please help me with this, is energy  conserved only along one axis ?

Comment: If you are only thinking about spatial axis (which I assume you do from your question), then energy is not a quantity related to any axis, and it is not a vector quantity, but a scalar, and therefore it cannot be 'conserved along a single axis'. Are you maybe referring to momentum?

Comment: Exactly. That's what my doubt is. I was going through a solution of a question where they conserved the energy only along the X-axis and that didn't really make sense to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Energy itself is not a vector, but the processes that involve it very often are.

Consider for example the work done by an object moving against a force, such as a projectile fired upwards against gravity. The displacement of the projectile from its initial position is a vector, and to get the work done by the object against gravity we take the magnitude of the product of the displacement vector with the weight force vector - thus obtaining a **scalar** quantity.

The conservation of energy principle simply tells us that the total amount of energy in a closed system remains the same - so that the amount of work done by our projectile moving against gravity depletes its kinetic energy by the same amount (neglecting other factors like air resistance). But for this calculation to 'work' we have to regard energy as a scalar.

In many moving-body problems it is possible to split the motion into horizontal and vertical components and consider each separately. However to do this relies on everything being linear, and many real problems are not like that.

Comment: I came across a question where a disc moving with a certain velocity hits another identical disc, at rest, at an angle alpha with the horizontal. When I went through the solution of the problem, they applied energy conservation along the X-axis, ie 1/2mu²cos² alpha = 1/2mv1x² + 1/2mv2² where ( v1x is the velocity of first disc after collision and v2 is the velocity second disc after collision). My point is, why have they considered only the x-component of the velocity vector. Shouldn't it be 1/2mu²? Is the given solution wrong?

Comment: Here's the question in case you need it: A ball moving translationally collides elastically with another, stationary, ball of the same mass. At the moment of impact the angle between the straight line passing through the centres of the balls and the direction of the initial motion of the striking ball is equal to α=45°. Assuming the balls to be smooth, the fraction η of the kinetic energy of the striking ball that turned into potential energy at the moment of the maximum deformation.